# How to use the > operator in the nodejs commander

Tags: node.js

Please I want to make a command that uses the > operator in the command line arguments
For example I want when the user enter this command in command line

```
name jack > ma
```

output will be

```
jack ma
```

So I used the commander to create command by writing this

```
app.command("name <firstName> > <lastName>").parse(process.argv)
```

but this not working because > operator is predefined in the command line as it is used for writing in file

So how to make this ?

Comment: What about using `name jack ">" ma`?

Comment: Putting the > operator inside quotes makes it as a string not operator and ouput comes jack >

Is there a way to override the original function of this operator as it is mainly used by ubuntu for writing in files ?

Comment: I think the user could override it in their own shell but you wouldn't be able to override it from this executable. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Well for mainly practice purpose I want to make file system command line application using nodejs and one of its functions is reading and writing to files ... so I want to use the > and < operators to read and write to files